# install component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

hi everyoneI have a probelm with my project in joomla

I try to install a new component and obtain this error

```
JFolder::create: No se pudo crear el directorio
¡Advertencia: No se pudo mover el archivo!
No se puede encontrar paquete de instalación
```

I set 777 permissions but dont work. any idea.

thanks

Comment: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=252418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than just 1 folder to be writeable. In you Joomla backend, go to:

**Site (top menu) >> System Information >> Directory Permissions**

and ensure that all of them are writable. If they are and you are still having problems, it might well be due to folder ownership, in which case you will most likely have to get in contact with you host.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Lodder I have the last two file no writable But have to change this?  htdocs/log y htdocs/cache

Comment: @user852610 - try making them writable just so be on the safe side and try installing the component again